# Retrieve username and password from text files and collect them in a log in variable(params)

Tags: authentication, filesystems, titanium, appcelerator

I have got a function that stores the username and password in each separate text files `(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "userName.txt")` and `(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "passWord.txt")` after the login has been confirmed valid by the webserver(php).

Now I need a function that retrieve the values(text content) from userName.txt and passWord.txt and collect these values in a var params that post them to the php-server on an event:

```
var params = {  
            username: username.value,  
            password: Ti.Utils.md5HexDigest(password.value)  
};
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking for advice or is there some error? Improve your question to get better answers here.

Comment: There is no error, I just wonder if anyone can give me a tip about how I can write a function that finds text files: userName.txt and passWord.txt in applicationDataDirectory(saved files) and get they're value and again put those values into a var params(above). The function will serve as a automatic log in credential for the app. userName.txt contain only a e-mail address and passWord.txt only a password(string).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Ti.App.Properties? It is designed for storing data just like this.

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString('username', username.value);
username.value = Ti.App.Properties.getString('username');
```

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties

If you must use files (which I do not recommend):

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'username.txt');
file.write(username.value);
username.value = file.read();
```